# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a python game. In its first line I have `import`ed `pygame`. I installed and did all the essential stuff for it but when I import it, it shows an error telling that:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pygame
```

Hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like pycharm or visual studio code? If so, it's possible that *it* doesn't know about the third-party module you installed — the IDE's documentation should explain how to do such installations so they will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way to install pygame is with pip tool, which Python uses to install packages.**

Run this in your terminal to install:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

To test it, run this in your terminal:

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

It works for me!